# Why is polygon "hole" being shaded in by Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I've been plotting complicated multipolygons via GeoJSON with the Google Maps JavaScript API and occasionally I notice that some "holes" get shaded in. I suspected my code was producing some malformed GeoJSON (e.g. exterior and interior rings having the same winding direction) so I tried to simplify the shape by reducing it to a single polygon and removing almost all vertices: the result is shown below.

I can't see anything wrong with the GeoJSON, and yet the hole is shaded the same colour as the rest of the polygon. I have tested this on Chrome and Firefox on macOS and Chrome on Windows.

I think (although my eyes/memory might be playing tricks) that this problem is intermittent, i.e. that if I refresh the map the hole renders correctly sometimes. However, I can't reproduce this now.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, or has anyone come across a bug like this before in Google Maps?

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 47,
      lng: -120
    },
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-124.125, 46.125],
            [-124.125, 45.125],
            [-119.875, 46.625],
            [-119.875, 48.875],
            [-124.125, 48.875],
            [-124.125, 46.125]
          ],
          [
            [-122.375, 47.125],
            [-122.375, 46.875],
            [-122.625, 46.875],
            [-122.625, 47.125],
            [-122.375, 47.125]
          ]
        ]

      }
    }]
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The winding direction of the outer polygon is wrong.

Related question: [Is the erratum about polygon point order in GeoJSON correct?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287910/is-the-erratum-about-polygon-point-order-in-geojson-correct)

Reversing the order of the outer polygon's coordinates makes the hole work.  Changing:

```
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [-124.125, 46.125],
        [-124.125, 45.125],
        [-119.875, 46.625],
        [-119.875, 48.875],
        [-124.125, 48.875],
        [-124.125, 46.125]
      ],
```

To:

```
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [ // polygon
        [-124.125, 46.125],
        [-124.125, 48.875],            
        [-119.875, 48.875],
        [-119.875, 46.625],
        [-124.125, 45.125],            
        [-124.125, 46.125]
      ],
```

Shows the hole.

[image]

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 47,
      lng: -120
    },
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [ // polygon
            [-124.125, 46.125],
            [-124.125, 48.875],            
            [-119.875, 48.875],
            [-119.875, 46.625],
            [-124.125, 45.125],            
            [-124.125, 46.125]
          ],
          [ // hole
            [-122.375, 47.125],
            [-122.375, 46.875],
            [-122.625, 46.875],
            [-122.625, 47.125],
            [-122.375, 47.125]
          ]
        ]

      }
    }]
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=&v=3.40&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't your code have both the external ring and the interior ring winding clockwise? The GeoJSON spec says "exterior rings are counterclockwise, and holes are clockwise". The Google Maps docs make the slightly weaker requirement that "...the points forming the inner path are wound in the opposite direction to those in the outer path, to form the hole."  

I think your working code violates these requirements whereas my code is compliant. I think this implies a bug in Google Maps, unless I'm missing something

Comment: The inner hole seems to work either way (at least at the present time).  I made the minimal changes to the posted code to display the hole.

Comment: I would say it is a bug in the way the Google Maps Javascript API v3 is parsing the GeoJSON, [geojsonlint.com](https://geojsonlint.com/) pops up a warning: `Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule`.  Looks like you already reported it: [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171177654).  Possibly related issue: [RFC 7946 GeoJSON non-compliance](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63581224)

Comment: Not sure why, but if you remove or slightly move the second point in the outer polygon, it works as well.  [fiddle/slightly moved](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u3qo5rvw/5/), [fiddle/removed](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u3qo5rvw/6/)  (I exported the GeoJson from the example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-polygon, it was valid per https://geojsonlint.com).

Comment: geojsonlint is a cool-looking tool - thanks for bringing it to my attention. I'd seen that removing some points fixed the issue when working with more complicated polygons so it's really looking like an actual bug in Google Maps. If only I could figure out what in particular Google Maps is bothered by, then I could potentially design a workaround... Thanks for your help with this - lots of food for thought.